# Google Dataflow - clarification around pricing for streaming pipeline with bounded data

Tags: streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am a bit confused about some of the Dataflow pricing around streaming:

I have a pipeline where at the very end , I am trying to load data into `BigQuery` using the `FILE_LOADS` method, but with a `triggering_frequency` set, however that seems to demand that the pipeline has to be a streaming pipeline. This is the only reason I need to set the pipeline as streaming. Everything else is perfectly batch, and the data source of the pipeline is also bounded (another BigQuery table).

Now if I enabled `--streaming`, what would be the effect of the pricing on this pipeline? Looking at the [pricing link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pricing#streaming-data), it says the following are billed:

> The volume of data ingested into your streaming pipeline
> The complexity of the pipeline
> The number of pipeline stages with shuffle operation or with stateful DoFns

Now, my question is will all these also apply to the previous steps/DoFns in my pipeline even though those are working on bounded data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will apply to the whole pipeline.

Your cost should still be relatively the same since your volume of data and pipeline haven't changed. The triggering_frequency merely changes how often a load job is triggered.

Why do you need to set this frequency though? Does the default behavior not work for your batch job? I'm not sure how the pipeline will terminate in this setup. Will you have to cancel it once everything is processed?

Comment: With the original batch pipeline, we have encountered transient errors (like timeout) with the FILE_LOADS write - the WriteToBigQuery internally partitions the data into multiple partitions and loads them into temporary tables, and copies them over the actual table, but if for some transient reason writing  to one of those partitions fails, the entire write fails and nothing is written. We were trying ways around that - like either use FILE_LOADS with triggering_frequency or streaming write, so that at least something gets written even if there is a failure, but the costing may be a concern.

Comment: Regarding you question of termination, I am not too sure either? Do any pipeline with `--streaming` option just keeps running unless you terminate it?

Comment: I assume so.  You may write the pipeline in a streaming style and let autoscaling manage how many workers are used based on your throughput. Or you can stick to a batch job but partitioning your output into different destinations manually. E.g. into https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables or just multiple tables sharded by different names.